# Commutative diagram with 2 blocks

Tags: amsmath, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Using the tikzcd package I would like to make the following diagram.

[image: commutative diagram]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to read the  `tikz-cd` documentation and try it first, post some code of your try and then ask for help. However here it is.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzcd}[ execute at end picture={\draw[->] (-1,0) arc[start angle=-180,delta angle=300,radius=3mm];}]
A \arrow[d, "\alpha"] \arrow[r]     & B \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "\beta"]    & C \arrow[d, "\gamma"]\\
D \arrow[r]                         & E \arrow[r]                       & F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to drawing and placing the circular arrow manually, you can use `\circlearrowleft` (scaled if you wish) on a `phantom` arrow from `A` to `E`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d, "\alpha"]\arrow[r]\arrow[dr, phantom, "\scalebox{2}{$\circlearrowleft$}"] & B \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "\beta"] & C \arrow[d, "\gamma"]\\
D \arrow[r] & E \arrow[r] & F
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```